# Error while publishing Xamarin.iOS IPA in Application Loader

Tags: xamarin.ios, application-loader

When I am trying to deliver my app through Application Loader I get multiple errors saying:
*ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file myapp.app/SwiftFrameworkSimulator/libsswiftCoreLocation.dylib" is not permitted.*

I see these files are packaged into my app, how do I stop them from getting packaged into my .ipa? What are these files, and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild your project? Have a look at these threads may help: [error-itms-90171](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85962/xamarin-forms-application-error-itms-90171-invalid-bundle-structure) and [invalid-bundle-structure](https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift/issues/28).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by manually deleting the SwiftFrameworkSimulator folder and it´s content from the archive, but I don´t know why such thing would be added in the first place.